Firebase update database with rules auth
I use vue js with firebase firestore database, at first my database rules is : allow read: if true; allow write: if true;and it worked fine, I've changed it to allow read: if true; allow write: if request.auth != null; and now it does not work with error Missing or insufficient permissions., how and where to config this auth in my project? anyone help me please? here is my code on update:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, onSnapshot, doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";


...............................
let docRef = doc(db, appConfig, appConfig.id);
updateDoc(docRef, updatedData)
    .then(() => {
        toast.add({
            severity: "success",
            summary: "Successful",
            detail: `Data saved successfully`,
            life: 3000,
        });
    })

code in detail how to config this auth

Hello, did you look at the Auth documentation? You need to ensure that th euse is authenticated before calling updateDoc(). The standard is to use a authentication state observer, but it all depend on your application flow/navigation.

@RenaudTarnec, thank you, I see it now
